# Referencing JS library in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, momentjs

I'm trying to reference a local library ("/moment.js") that is located in my root folder in my Chrome extension script. I've gotten the function to work in Google App Script as a Sheets extension and as a script referencing the library after loaded in HTML, but not as a Chrome extension.

Here is my manifest.json

```
  "name": "RE-Toolkit",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Real Estate Toolkit",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["/moment.js"]
    }
  ],

  //ICON
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "512": "/home-icon.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "/popup.html"
  },

  "web_accessible_resources": ["moment.js", "script.js", "popup.html"]
}
```

I think after including this resource in the manifest, I should be able to reference "moment()" in my script using

```
var m = moment();
console.log(m);
```

but so far it's not working. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: [remove the `/` in content_scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts)

Comment: Still doesn't work. All references (icon, popup, script) behave the same whether or not I have the `/`

Comment: I know. Did you read the rest of the information about using content_scripts in that article? (also, how are you building this? `web-ext` or some other solution)

Comment: Remove the "content_scripts" section, remove "web_accessible_resources" section, and use a standard `<script src="popup.js"></script>` and similar for other scripts in popup.html before the closing </body> tag. See also the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Interesting. It says "Extension UI pages, such as a popup, can contain ordinary HTML pages with JavaScript logic," but I thought that Javascript wasn't allowed in HTML in manifest version 2. 

Anyway, my extension works entirely as intended now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've already found a solution, but i'll answer this question anyway to possibly help someone else facing the same issue.

In order to fix this problem you have to adjust the Content Security Policy. In short, Google's CSP is a mechanism used to block resources used by the extension that isn't local. This means (example) you wouldn't be able to use a Jquery CDN, but downloading jquery and referencing its local file is acceptable. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

To allow your extension to use resources outside of your program, you must explicitly state it in your **manifest.json**. In order to do this, you must add the "content_security_policy" property in your manifest.json like so:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
```

So basically, content_security_policy value is a string. Replace the example.com reference to the file you'd like to use.

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js; object-src 'self'"
```

For those of you who want to add multiple outside resources to your extension, add it after your first resource with a space separating the two. You must add the resource(s) after the "Script-src 'self'" but before the semicolon. Don't forget to also add the cdn file links to your code as well. Hope this helps someone.